# Open module in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, modularity, prism-6

I try to open a module resolved by a special directory

`return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @"..\..\modules" };`

and want to show it in a new `Window`.

How can I do that?

My approach so far:

```
public void OpenInNewWindow(string regionName)
{
    var cc = new ContentControl();
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(regionName, () => cc);

    new Window
    {
        Content = cc
    }.Show();
}
```

But that seems not to work. My `Window` is empty.

Comment: My goal is just to load an module in a new window. It's just like a tool library. There are many tools with it own views services and so on. In my main program i had only a button "open xyz-plugin" to run this module. This works really fine in my shell (just a content-control with a specified region). But I want to run the module in a new window, thats my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are dealing with `navigation` and this line:

```
var cc = new ContentControl();
```

Is for demonstration only. I guess you should add a region name to the content control before assigning it to the view or before calling `RegisterViewWithRegion`, like this.

```
var contentControl = new ContentControl();
RegionManager.SetRegionName(contentControl, regionName);
var window = new Window
{
    Content = contentControl
}.Show();
```

`RegionManager.SetRegionName` is an attached property, which is equivalent to:

```
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion"></ContentControl>
```

Comment: thats exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't read your question properly the first time. I should've read your question carefully and therefore answered your question earlier.